# Memory in solidity with different types of data

Tags: variables, memory, types, solidity

When creating a function that accepts an arguments like int, uint, string and so on why does it needs to specify that string is a memory but when passing a uint it doesn't needs to specify that its a memory
example:

```
contract SompleContract{
    string favWord;
    uint favNum;
// in here we have 2 arguments _favNum and _favWord but passing _favWord needs to be memory
    function simpleFunction(uint _favNum, string memory _favWord) public {
        favNum = _favNum;
        favWord = _favWord;
    }

}
```

why does it has to be memory when its a string (_favWord in this case) and not when its a uint (_favNum) and also what kind of data types has to be specified that it's memory when passing it into a function

Answer (score 1):

Data location (`memory`, `calldata` or `storage`) needs to be specified for all [reference types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#reference-types). In Solidity, `string` is treated as dynamic-size array of bytes - and array is a reference type.